# Crash with Uwp in Xamarin.Forms when memory reaches more than 1200mb

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, maps, xamarin.uwp, arcgis-runtime-net

Working with the map-related application(ArcGIS runtime) using Xamarin.Forms. A crash happened with Uwp devices while navigating and loading the map page. While checking memory its reaches up to 1200 MB at the time of crashing. Is this due to a memory leak or How to resolve this issue?

Comment: is there an exception causing the crash?  What is it?

Comment: While crashing this popup only shows "A debugger is attached to myapp.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception.To debug this exception detach the current debugger"

Comment: Well, fix that.  Or add some exception handling/logging around the suspect code.  AppCenter.ms has tools for logging unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing, it's hard to say if this is due to a memory leak, or because you do actually need access to that much memory. If you need more memory, compile as x64. If it's a memory issue, please try v100.13, as that did have several memory improvements.